# Arrête de bouger dans tous les sens (pour) que je puisse finir de te coiffer

Tags: conjonctions

*Manuel d'une fille culottée* de Candace Bushnell :

> ...Obligations de grand soeur ou pas, je m'attends un peu à ce qu'elle
> me dise de me mêler de mes affaires.
>
> -- D'accord, finit-elle par déclarer. Je les mettrai.
>
> Cette fois-ci, je ne prends pas la peine de cacher mon sourire.
>
> -- Parfait, dis-je, satisfaite. Maintenant arrête de bouger dans tous les sens **que** je puisse finir de te coiffer.*

À mon avis, il manque *pour* entre *sens* et *que*. Est-ce que la phrase telle quelle est correcte ?

Comment: À l'oral c'est parfaitement correct et courant, et personnellement je rajouterais une virgule après *sens*.

Answer (score 5):

Oui, la phrase est correcte.

TLFi: [**Que**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que)

> **I.** − Emplois conjonctionnels
> **A.** − Conjonction de subordination
> **6.** [Introduit une subordonnée circonstancielle]
> **c)** [Circonstancielle finale]
> **β)** [Employé seul après un impératif] *Asseyez-vous là, que nous causions, me dit-elle* (Fromentin, *Dominique*, 1863, p. 114). *Zoé, tu es (...) une sœur très aimable. Viens que je t'embrasse* (A. France, *Bergeret*, 1901, p. 82).

Utiliser ***pour*** aurait été possible mais le style aurait été un peu lourd.

> Maintenant arrête de bouger dans tous les sens **pour** que je puisse finir de te coiffer.

Une autre possibilité aurait été :

> Maintenant arrête de bouger dans tous les sens **afin** que je puisse finir de te coiffer.