# Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie (parce) que Jeck était revenu avec du

Tags: conjonctions

*La revanche d'une fille trahie* d'Alexandra Larochelle :

Sonia, la narratrice, texte à Anthonie, son amie, qu'elle pense qu'elle a cassé le nez à Jech. Anthonie lui écrit *Hein ?!?!?*

> Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie **que** Jeck était
> revenu avec du papier de toilette bien enfoncé dans ses deux narines.
>
> Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie **parce que** Jeck
> était revenu avec du...

Est-ce que la première phrase est préférable car moins lourde ? ([source](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49830/arr%C3%AAte-de-bouger-dans-tous-les-sens-pour-que-je-puisse-finir-de-te-coiffer))

Answer (score 3):

Les deux phrases sont valides et leurs sens sont très proches.

Dans les deux cas, la personne qui s'exprime n'a pas eu le temps de répondre au *Hein ?!?!?*

Dans la première phrase, la conjonction *que* indique que l'arrivée de Jeck a immédiatement suivi cette absence de réponse. Les événements se suivent sans qu'une relation de causalité soit explicitement établie.

Dans la deuxième, la séquence des événements est identique mais on indique clairement que la cause de l'absence de réponse, c'est l'arrivée de Jeck.

Comment: _Dans la première, la réponse, c'était_ Non, je vais ajouter le contexte à ma question.

Comment: Ah oui ! L'ajout de la fin de la phrase change son sens.