# Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck était / est revenu avec du

Tags: passé-composé, plus-que-parfait

*La revanche d'une fille trahie* d'Alexandra Larochelle :

Sonia, la narratrice, texte à Anthonie, son amie, qu'elle pense qu'elle a cassé le nez à Jech. Anthonie lui écrit *Hein ?!?!?*

> Je **n'ai pas eu** le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck **était revenu**
> avec du...

L'auteure emploie le plus-que-parfait *Jeck était revenu* parce que cet évènement est antérieur à *je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre*.

Je pense qu'il est aussi possible d'utiliser le passé composé *Jeck est revenu* ici, car les deux évènements se produisent presque simultanément. Est-ce correct ?

Ajout :

Dans le fil ([Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie (parce) que Jeck était revenu avec du](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/50077/je-nai-pas-eu-le-temps-de-r%C3%A9pondre-%C3%A0-anthonie-parce-que-jeck-%C3%A9tait-revenu-ave)), il est écrit :

> Dans la première phrase, la conjonction que indique que l'arrivée de
> Jeck a **immédiatement** suivi cette absence de réponse. Les événements **se**
> **suivent** sans qu'une relation de causalité soit explicitement établie.

Donc, à mon avis, le passé composé est possible dans cette phrase et même il serait plus logique de l'employer. Sauf que l'auteure utilise l'imparfait dans cette phrase. À mon avis, les deux sont possibles, mais j'aimerais savoir quelle variante est meilleure.

Answer (score 3):

Cette utilisation de la locution conjonctive ***pas** [...] **que*** qui introduit une proposition subordonnée circonstancielle de temps est rare. Ce qui est beaucoup plus courant, d'autant plus après un verbe comme *répondre* qui peut être transitif, c'est un ***que*** conjonction de subordination qui introduit un complément d'objet direct (***Répondre quoi** ? **Répondre que** Jeck est revenu...*). Lors de ma première lecture et en l'absence de contexte, j'avais retenu cet usage et donc mal interprété cette phrase qui est effectivement ambiguë.

Voici par exemple une forme non ambiguë d'un ***que*** similaire utilisant la locution conjonctive plus courante ***à peine** [...] **que*** :

> *A peine étais-je revenu de Brest à Combourg, qu’il se fit dans mon existence une révolution; l’enfant disparut et l’homme se montra avec ses joies qui passent et ses chagrins qui restent.*
> Chateaubriand, *Mémoires d'outre-tombe*, 1849

Dans le texte d'Alexandra Larochelle, la proposition circonstancielle indique l'arrivée soudaine de Jeck.

La seule contrainte est l'utilisation de l'indicatif, beaucoup de temps sont possibles :

1. Le plus-que-parfait indique que le retour est achevé lors de la scène décrite :

   > Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck était revenu avec du...
2. Si on souhaite indiquer la simultanéité des deux propositions, on doit pouvoir utiliser le passé simple ou le passé composé:

   > Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck revint avec du...

   > Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck est revenu avec du...
3. On peut aussi dire que le retour de Jeck prenait du temps, et utiliser l'imparfait :

   > Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck revenait avec du...
4. Enfin, on peut aussi basculer vers le présent de narration :

   > Je n'ai pas eu le temps de répondre à Anthonie que Jeck revient avec du...

Les choix 1. et 3. me semblent les plus naturels.

Comment: Mais en fait Sonia, la narratrice, veut dire autre chose à son amie, qu'elle craint qu'elle ait cassé le nez de Jeck. Son amie lui demande comment ça a pu arriver, et Sonia veut lui répondre, mais à ce moment-là Jech arrive.

Comment: Oui, il aurait fallu que j'aie la phrase entière pour le comprendre. J'aurais dû demander avec quoi Jeck était revenu.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je ne reçois pas toutes les notifications, j'ai vu ton ajout en revenant vers ce fil.